# Which logical system/framework is the underlying basis of "highschool" Mathematics, and what would happen if you subbed it out for another?

Tags: logic

Question part 1:

There are a variety of different formal logical systems or frameworks. Some are contradiction tolerant, while more traditional ones follow the rules of aristotle (including the principle of non-contradiction).

I was wondering if there's a name for the logical system underlying "highschool level" mathematics (which would include things such as euclidean geometry, cartesian geometry, integral and differential calculus, algebra including complex numbers etc).

Question Part 2:
I was wondering what would be the broad flow on effects (or at least some specific and interesting examples) of what would happen to "highschool" level mathematics if this underlying logical system were to be replaced with an alternate one. For (a loose) example, assuming aristotelian logic underlies modern mathematics, what would happen to the simple notion "1+1=2" if we were to replace it with Buddhist logic (which is contradiction-tolerant under certain circumstances, cf Graham Priest and his "Principle of non-Triviality")

Post Script:
I actually ask this question as a student of human culture and comparative religion. I'm fascinated by the fact that mathematics and logic (among many other things) developed differently in different cultures across the world and am wondering if different cultural contexts have any impact today on accepted mathematical axioms and theorems. Mathematics is often made out to be completely objective and truthful, but I wonder if there are any culturally specific differences to be found today in how mathematics is done in different cultural contexts.

Comment: For 1: [Classical Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical) and "basic" [Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/).

Comment: For 2, see e.g. [Inconsistent Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent).